# Display Timezone (e.g. PST) in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, timezone, coldfusion-9

I am trying to display client's timezone besides the timestamp.
E.g 4:13 PST

I tried using GetTimeZoneInfo() but the only way I could think of is by getting the offset in hours and then determining through an array of hard coded values.

Other way around I found was using java.util.TimeZone class. Following is the code I have tried ---

```
 <cfset tz = CreateObject("java", "java.util.TimeZone")> 
<cfset tz = tz.getDefault()> 
<cfoutput>TimeZone:#tz.getDisplayName(false, 1)#</cfoutput>
```

This gives me output as Central Standard Time.

Any further help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you mention above gets the *server's* TZ, not the client's.

If you want the client's TZ, you should read the comments against this other, [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript). These all revolve around using the `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` method. This does only give you the offset from UTC though, not the more familiar GMT / BST etc.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I tried GetTimeZoneInfo() method which gives me this offset, but I was thinking of some way rather than figuring out based on some hardcoded values stored and then matching it to this offset value.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's the only option you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing your users to select their time zone instead of getting it from the browser which potentially could be inaccurate, or they are coming from database values such as time zone per city, etc, or you simply need to extract the abbreviation from any datetime value, you can parse it out of the return value from `LSDateTimeFormat()` with the "long" mask.

```
function tzabbr(required date dttm, string tz = "", string locale = GetLocale()) {
  var str = tz == "" 
    ? LSDateTimeFormat(dttm, "long", locale)
    : LSDateTimeFormat(dttm, "long", locale, tz)
  return ListLast(str, " ")
}
// Usage Examples
dttm = Now()
tzServ = tzabbr(dttm)
tzWest = tzabbr(dttm, "US/Pacific")
tzEast = tzabbr(dttm, "US/Eastern")
```

https://trycf.com/gist/144aa0399ea80127a3aa1d11a74fc79b/acf2021?theme=monokai